# Build failed: Gradle build failed with unknown error. Please see logs for the "Run gradlew" phase

Tags: reactjs, react-native, gradle, expo, admob

I have faced this sort of error while bundling
any suggestions on how to solve this error
I have tried it by removing extra dependencies but still it doesn't work

Moreover, I have also removed the node modules and re-installed them if any module was unknowingly removed by mistake.
But still it doesn't work.

could be any problem but I can`t resolve it
I have been facing and trying to solve this since past 2 days

I have made a sample default bundle
And it worked
but this app isn`t bundling
I am using Expo-react-native

````
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip
10%.
20%.
30%.
40
%
50
%.
60%.
70%.
80%.
90%
100%
Welcome to Gradle 7.3.3!
Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Easily declare new test suites in Java projects
 - Support for Java 17
 - Support for Scala 3
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/release-notes.html
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build
Unable to list file systems to check whether they can be watched. Assuming all file systems can be watched. Reason: Could not query file systems: could not open mount file (errno 2: No such file or directory)
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
'compileJava' task (current target is 1.8) and 'compileKotlin' task (current target is 11) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/ReactExtension.kt: (10, 37): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/ReactExtension.kt: (119, 30): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/ReactExtension.kt: (135, 26): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/ReactExtension.kt: (155, 32): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/ReactExtension.kt: (161, 31): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/ReactExtension.kt: (169, 36): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/ReactPlugin.kt: (100, 48): 'reactRoot: DirectoryProperty' is deprecated. reactRoot was confusing and has been replace with rootto point to your root project and reactNativeDir to point to the folder of the react-native NPM package
w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/TaskConfiguration.kt: (10, 37): 'ApplicationVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/TaskConfiguration.kt: (11, 37): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/TaskConfiguration.kt: (12, 37): 'LibraryVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/TaskConfiguration.kt: (28, 51): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/TaskConfiguration.kt: (131, 12): 'ApplicationVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/TaskConfiguration.kt: (132, 12): 'LibraryVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/TaskConfiguration.kt: (252, 14): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileJava
[stderr] 
Note: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/codegen/generator/SchemaJsonParser.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[stderr] 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:processResources
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:classes
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:jar
> Configure project :app
Unable to detect AGP versions for included builds. All projects in the build should use the same AGP version. Class name for the included build object: org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuild$IncludedBuildImpl_Decorated.
> Configure project :expo-eas-client
Warning: The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.
> Configure project :expo-structured-headers
Warning: The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.
> Configure project :expo-updates-interface
Warning: The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.
> Configure project :expo
Using expo modules
  - expo-ads-admob (13.0.0)
  - expo-ads-facebook (11.2.0)
  - expo-application (4.1.0)
- expo-constants (13.1.1)
  - expo-eas-client (0.2.1)
  - expo-error-recovery (3.1.0)
  - expo-facebook (12.2.0)
- expo-file-system (14.0.0)
- expo-font (10.1.0)
  - expo-json-utils (0.3.0)
  - expo-keep-awake (10.1.1)
  - expo-manifests (0.3.0)
  - expo-modules-core (0.9.2)
  - expo-splash-screen (0.15.1)
  - expo-structured-headers (2.2.1)
  - expo-system-ui (1.2.0)
  - expo-updates (0.13.2)
[stderr] 
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
[stderr] 
1:
[stderr] 
Task failed with an exception.
[stderr] 
-----------
[stderr] 
* Where:
[stderr] 
Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-ad-manager/android/build.gradle' line: 23
[stderr] 
* What went wrong:
[stderr] 
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-ad-manager'.
[stderr] 
> Plugin with id 'maven' not found.
[stderr] 
* Try:
[stderr] 
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] 
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] 
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] 
==============================================================================
[stderr] 
2: Task failed with an exception.
[stderr] 
-----------
[stderr] 
* What went wrong:
[stderr] 
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-ad-manager'.
[stderr] 
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
[stderr] 
* Try:
[stderr] 
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] 
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] 
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] 
==============================================================================
[stderr] 
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] 
BUILD FAILED in 2m 24s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
6 actionable tasks: 6 executed
Unable to list file systems to check whether they can be watched. The whole state of the virtual file system has been discarded. Reason: Could not query file systems: could not open mount file (errno 2: No such file or directory)
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. Please see logs for the "Run gradlew" phase.```
````

Answer (score 0):

You have Three choices to fix this error

## Choice 1

Downgrade gradle from android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties change
distributionUrl

from

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
```

## Choice 2

Make the changes found in this link https://github.com/NZME/react-native-ad-manager/blob/master/android/build.gradle in your node_modules/react-native-ad-manager/build.gradle.

Also Change these lines

```
def DEFAULT_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION = 28
def DEFAULT_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION = '28.0.3'
```

to this

```
def DEFAULT_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION = 30
def DEFAULT_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION = '30.0.2'
```

## Choice 3

Find a replacement for react-native-ad-manager which is updated and maintained for gradle 7+

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

check the react-native-ad-manager in your node-modules, that is where the error is coming from

Comment: suggest the very common things that already mentioned in another answer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34685410)